# external function called from another contract

Tags: solidity

I heard external functions are a nice performance improvement, when called  from outside the contract.
Can I use an external function when it's called from another contract ( not by ethereum account )? Example

```
contract One {
    Two two;
    function makeCall() {
         two.someExternalFunction();
    }
}

contract Two {
    function someExternalFunction() external {
       //...
    }
}
```

it compiles well, but should it be used that way, or may there arise some consequences ?

Answer (score 1):

`external` functions are readonly functions that have the ability to return dynamic arrays (which was not possible before solidity 0.4.23). These functions can not be called internally (unless you explicitly use the keyword `this` : `this.externalfn()`) but are supposed to be called from outside the contract.

The good thing about `external` functions that they are read only so they work great when only read access is allowed from a certain smart contract.